# JSON with Python: No expected validation errors with jsonschema

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I have defined a schema and used it to validate JSON objects but I never get the expected ValidationError. For example:

```py
>>> from jsonschema import validate
>>> schema = {
...   "type" : "object",
...   "properties" : {
...       "address" : {"type" : "string"},
...    },
... }
>>>
>>> schema
{'type': 'object', 'properties': {'address': {'type': 'string'}}}
>>> validate(instance={"address" : "123 Main St.", "price" : 34.99}, schema=schema)
>>> validate(instance={"address1" : "123 Main St.", "price" : 34.99}, schema=schema)
>>>
>>> validate(instance={"addresdvzdvfafczscss1" : "123 Main St.", "price" : 34.99}, schema=schema)
>>> validate(instance={"addresdvzdvfafczscss1" : "123 Main St.", "price" : 34.99}, schema=schema)
# doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
>>>
>>> validate(instance={"addresdvzdvfafczscss1" : "123 Main St.",}, schema=schema)  # doctest: +IGNO
RE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
>>>
>>> type(schema)
<class 'dict'>
>>> str(schema)
"{'type': 'object', 'properties': {'address': {'type': 'string'}}}"
>>> validate(instance={"addresdvzdvfafczscss1" : 123,}, schema=schema)  # doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTIO
N_DETAIL
>>>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what you *expected* to get as an error, but I'm going to guess that you want the validation to complain that the "address" property is missing. To achieve that, you need to use the `required` keyword, so try:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [ "address" ],
  "properties": {
    "address": {"type": "string"}
  }
}
```

You may also want to say "no other properties other than address are permitted" -- which can be done with `"additionalProperties": false`.